# c# base class method returns derived class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

So I have an app calling a *LOAD* of WebServices, all of which have a response class, each response class is derived from ResponseBase

```
public abstract record ResponseBase<T>
{
    public HashSet<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; }

    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public virtual string Message => Success ? "Success" : string.Join(", ", ErrorMessages);

    public IEnumerable<T> Results { get; set; }
    public T Result { get; set; }
}
```

Now I currently create new responses like this:

```
var results = SomeService.GetSomeResults();
return new SomeDerivedResponse() { Success = true; Results = results }
```

For brevity, clarity, general code cleanliness what I'd *LIKE* to do is some more like:

```
var results = SomeService.GetSomeResults();
return new SomeDerivedResponse().WithSuccess(results);
```

WithSuccess() will just assign Success = true and Results = results accordingly

Without having to put the same WithSuccess() method in each of the derived response classes (Theres hundreds of them). I almost got there with a generic WithSuccess() method in the base class but it returns the base class, not the derived class, meaning I have this double-take:

```
return new SomeDerivedResponse().WithSuccess<SomeDerivedResponse>(results);
```

Any way I can either tell the compiler what the inference is, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are your response classes mutable?

Comment: @Dai - I have no idea, not my project, not my circus, not my monkeys. Not how I would have done any it. I just work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using generic extension methods like this should work:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static T WitSuccess<T, R>(this T t, IEnumerable<R> r) where T : ResponseBase<R>
    {
        // your logic here
        return t;
    }

    public static T WitSuccess<T, R>(this T t, R r) where T : ResponseBase<R>
    {
         // your logic here
        return t;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
public record SomeDerivedResponse : ResponseBase<int>{}
public record SomeDerivedResponse1<T> : ResponseBase<T>{}

new SomeDerivedResponse().WitSuccess(new []{1});
new SomeDerivedResponse1<int>().WitSuccess(1);
```

Comment: What's impressive is you got that I had two types of response (IEnumerable and single object) and coded an answer for both. Apart from a small spelling mistake, worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @Tod was glad to help!